# Responsive web layout issue

Tags: html, css

Does anybody can figure out how to keep the images of the gallery of getting out of the image box when i size down the windows or different resolution devices.

Issue:

[image]

Code:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>BlackBird </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <header class="background">
      <div class="logo"></div>
    </header>
    <section class="conteudo">
      <article>
      </article>
      <div class="bubble-wrapper">
        <article>
        </article>
      </div>
      <article>
        <hr>
        <h1>Galeria</h1>
      </article>
      <div class="img-box">
          <img src="images/gallery/1.jpg">
          <img src="images/gallery/2.jpg">
          <img src="images/gallery/8.jpg">
          <img src="images/gallery/4.jpg">
          <img src="images/gallery/6.jpg">
          <img src="images/gallery/7.jpg">
      </div>
  <footer>      
  </footer>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.img-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: black;
}
.img-box img {
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-top: 37px;
}
.img-box img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please review [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should include any relevant code. Right now, looking at an image it could be anyone's guess as how to fix **your specific issue**.

Comment: Float the images and clear the containing box maybe? It's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Basically what I want is for the images to remain inside the black square when I downsize the windows (and at other resolutions for that matter) which is not happening atm. I already added the viewport tag on the html so I have no idea what could be causing this \:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What causes the wrapping based on the code you posted is most likely that each `img` has its 15% width PLUS 18px padding. This adds up to be wider than the window width when you shrink the window, so the images wrap to a 2nd row.

The reason the 2nd row of images extends outside the black box is because you've set a fixed height of 400px on the `img-box` element.

One option is to use percentage-based padding between images instead of fixed 18px, and either set the img-box overflow to scroll, or allow it to have a variable height.

Also look into using media queries to adjust the layout at different screen widths, for example switching to a single column of images when it's a narrow width, changing the max image width, making them smaller thumbnails, etc. You could use something like [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as well.

Comment: Thanks ... You really helped a lot i used the overflow to scroll and used percentages in the padding and it worked great. You saved my final college work !!!

Comment: And the link to CSS flexbox seems pretty good i need to read it for my next work .